# Inflating a layout(activity) properly with left panel

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-inflate

```
    public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

        public PlanetFragment() {
            // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View slidepane = null;
            int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
            String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];
if (i == 0)
{
    slidepane = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_cam_way, container, false);
}

if (i == 1)
{

    // startActivity(new Intent(this.getActivity(),com.project.smyrna.camway.FileBrowser.class));
    slidepane = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_from_gallery, container, false);
}

if (i == 2 )
{
    slidepane = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_settings, container, false);
}



if (slidepane == null)
{

    //slidepane = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_cam_way, container, false);
}

return slidepane;

        }
    }
```

Hi,

I have that code for inflating a layout inside of that :

[image: Left Sliding Panel]

but it doesn't work when i touch my photos or settings. its Force Closes

```
    12-14 22:42:58.011: D/AndroidRuntime(23679): Shutting down VM
12-14 22:42:58.011: W/dalvikvm(23679): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41fcbc68)
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679): Process: com.dogaozkaraca.camway, PID: 23679
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.surfaceCreated(GLSurfaceView.java:525)
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:572)
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679):    at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679):    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:175)
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679):    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1871)
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
12-14 22:42:58.011: E/AndroidRuntime(23679):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i want to load different activities(layouts) with that draggable left panel.

If you want to understand what im doing : you can download camway app from playstore....

i will move photos and settings buttons to left panel :)

I want to get rid of that stupid errors. :) :)

Hope you understand my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer by trying :)

We should load stuff before inflating an xml activity :)
because it only loads xml activity file . So all other stuff in xml's java file won't include. :)

So we need to load these stuff before inflating.

Like this...

Before :

```
if (i == 2 )
{
    slidepane = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_settings, container, false);
}
```

after :

```
if (i == 2 )
{ 
// load all stuff here 
// like an listview things :) 
// or custom libraries stuff 
// and then load them here again :)
    slidepane = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_settings, container, false);
}
```